# Covariance matrix "adaptation" to a set of new data

Tags: linear-algebra, covariance

Let's say I have a covariance matrix $\Sigma$ computed using a set of vectors $\{X_1, .. X_n\}$. Given a set of new vectors $\{Y_1, .. Y_m\}$ where $m<<n$, is there a way to do a kind of "adaptation" to $\Sigma$ and make it take into account the $Y_i$ vectors without having to recompute the covariance matrix using the whole vectors set $\{X_1, .. X_n, Y_1, .. Y_m\}$ ?

My goal is just to do the computation faster without loosing a lot in terms of precision (in my case $n$ is around 15000 and $m$ is around 30 and the vectors dimension is 1000).

Thanks !

Comment: See http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/30495 and http://www.emathzone.com/tutorials/basic-statistics/combined-variance.html But watch out: the first link assumes you have sample variances (*i.e.* divided by $n-1$) while the second one assumes population variances (*i.e.* divided by $n$). Apart from that the two are equivalent.

Comment: @Rahul thanks a lot ! The link responds to my question .